# terms for each field vs values for each field in _all elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I just started learning elasticsearch and would like to know what is the difference between terms and value in the following sentence that I copied from [elasticsearch website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html):

> "It is important to note that the _all field combines **the original values from each field** as a string. It does not combine **the terms from each field**.

While I understand what a *value* is, I have been scratching my head over *terms* for each field!
Can someone help me what it means, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph preceding the one you have pasted gives some explanation:

> The date_of_birth field in the above example is recognised as a date field and so will index a single term representing 1970-10-24 00:00:00 UTC. The _all field, however, treats all values as strings, so the date value is indexed as the three string terms: "1970", "24", "10".

In other words, the `_all` field takes the original values from the indexed document and **runs them through its own analyzer**, producing its own terms which are then stored in the index. It does not use the `terms` produced by analyzers of other fields.

One example is given in the paragraph I've pasted above. It explains that the `date_of_birth` field will be recognized as a `date` type and therefore will analyze and store the field value as a single term `1970-10-24 00:00:00 UTC`. So if you will try to match the `date_of_birth` field with a `match` query like this:

```
{ "query": { "match: { "date_of_birth": "24 10" } } }
```

You won't find that document because the parser won't be able to parse the provided value as a date.

On the other hand, if you will run the same query on the `_all` field, you will definitely find that document:

```
{ "query": { "match: { "_all": "24 10" } } }
```

Because, as the documentation suggests, the `_all` field will include following `text` type terms: `["1970", "10", "24"]`.

Let's look at another example. Assume you have the following `mapping` of `user` type:

```
"user": { 
    "properties": { 
        "nickname": { "type": "keyword"  }, 
        "name": { "type": "text"  }, 
        "age": { "type": "integer" }  
    }
}
```

And you index the following document:

```
{
    "nickname": "Super-Man",
    "name": "John",
    "age": 25
}
```

Elasticsearch will analyze the fields of this document according to their types, eventually storing following terms for each of these fields:

- `_all`: `["super", "man", "john", "25"]` - all strings
- `nickname`: `["Super-Man"]`
- `name`: `["john"]`
- `age`: `[25]` - integer

Therefore, if you will try to find this document using a `match` (or a `term`) query where `nickname` equals to `super` you won't find it. Because `nickname` field was analyzed as a `keyword`, you must use the exact string to find it - `"Super-Man"`.

But if you try to find this document using a `match` query where `_all` equals to `super`, you will find it.

On the other hand, if you try to find this document using a `term` query over the `_all` field an integer value `25`, you won't find it. Again, because `_all` field is just a `text` field:

```
{ "query": { term": { "_all": 25} } }
```

But running the same query on the `age` field will return the document:

```
{ "query": { term": { "age": 25} } }
```

Comment: Thanks @smnh, very through explanation.  . Just a quick question: do you think _all can also  be used with multi_match and type phrase? I am just curious to know if I am looking for an exact phrase _all can be used

Comment: Yes, you could use `_all` field with `multi_match` of phrase type. But take in mind that it will analyze the searched phrase differently, based on the field you are matching on. For example for the _all field, it will split the phrase by spaces, while for another field specified in `multi_match.fields` it will use the analyzer that was specified for that field. Also it may match phrases of two different fields. For example if you index `{"name": "Bob", "tag": "world"}` and then try to match a phrase "bob world" on _all field, you might find your document although the phrase is from two fields.